# What is $\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow0} \left(\alpha\log^2{\alpha}\right)$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

What is the limit of $\alpha\log^2{\alpha}$ as $\alpha\rightarrow0$?, these are my workings so far:

\begin{align}
\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow0} \left(\alpha\log^2{\alpha}\right)
%
&= 
%
\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow0} \left(\frac{\alpha}{\log^{-2}{\alpha}}\right)\\
%
&= 
%
\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow0} 
\left(
-\frac{1}{2}
\left\{
\frac{\alpha}{\log^{-3}{\alpha}}
\right\}
\right)
\\
%
&= 
%
\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow0} 
\left(
\frac{1}{6}
\left\{
\frac{\alpha}{\log^{-4}{\alpha}}
\right\}
\right)
\\
%
&= \cdots \\
%
%
&= 
%
\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow0} 
\left(
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}
\left[
\frac{\left(-1\right)^n}{n!}
\left\{
\frac{\alpha}{\log^{-(n+1)}\alpha}
\right\}
\right]
\right)\\
%
%
&= 
%
\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow0} 
\left(
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}
\left[
\frac{\left(-\alpha\right)^n}{n!}
\log^{(n+1)}\alpha
\right]
\right)
\end{align}

However I am now slightly stuck!

EDIT: Oh jeez, for a fixed $\alpha>0$

\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}
\left[
\frac{\left(-\alpha\right)^n}{n!}
\log^{(n+1)}\alpha
\right] = 0
\end{align}

doesn't it?

Comment: Put $\alpha = e^{-u}$ and take $u \to \infty$ ie., 

$$\lim_{u \to \infty}e^{-u}(-u)^2 =\lim_{u \to \infty} \frac{u^2}{e^u} \leq \lim_{u \to \infty}\frac{u^2}{1 + u + \frac{u^2}{2} + \frac{u^3}{6}} = 0$$

A more general argument shows $$\lim_{\alpha \to 0} \alpha^{\epsilon} (\log \alpha)^M=0$$

for all $\epsilon>0$ and $M \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: This is a much nicer method. Is mine correct?

Comment: The algebra is quite wrong. $$\frac{\alpha}{\log^{-2}(\alpha)} \neq  -\frac{1}{2} \frac{\alpha}{\log^{-3}(\alpha)}$$

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 that's L'Hospital's rule

Comment: Oh, haha, oops :P

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 no problem ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\alpha>0$, you can set $\alpha=\beta^2$, so your limit becomes
$$
\lim_{\beta\to0}4(\beta\log\beta)^2
$$
and it's known that $\lim\limits_{\beta\to0}\beta\log\beta=0$.

Comment: Thank you for this, this appears to be the most elegant solution :D

Answer (score 2):

If you know that:

$$ \forall \alpha,\beta \in ]0,+\infty[, \, \lim \limits_{x \to -\infty} e^{\alpha x}\vert x \vert^{\beta} = 0 \tag{1}$$

Then, it follows that:

$$ \forall \alpha,\beta \in ]0,+\infty[, \, \lim \limits_{\substack{x \to 0 \\ x > 0}} x^{\alpha} \vert \ln(x) \vert^{\beta} = 0. $$

All you need to prove is $(1)$. This is the same as Equation $(2)$ in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1164895/prove-that-lim-limits-x-to-infty-frac-log-xbxa-0-and-lim-li).

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)=x\ln(x)^2$

$f'(x)=\ln(x)\left(\ln(x)+2\right)\quad$ near $0$ we have $\ln(x)\to-\infty$ so $f'>0$.

Since near zero $f\ \nearrow\ $ positive and continuous, it admits a limit $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=\ell\ge 0$.

But $\underbrace{f(x)}_{\to \ell}=x\ln(\sqrt{x}^2)^2=x(2\ln(\sqrt{x}))^2=4\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{x}\ln(\sqrt{x})^2)=\underbrace{4\sqrt{x}}_{\to 0}\ \underbrace{f(\sqrt{x})}_{\to \ell}\to 0$

Then $\ell=0$ is forced.

Comment: Thank you for your input :) It's nice to see so many different solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Write $a \log^2a=\frac{\log^2a}{ \frac{1}{a}}$ and aply  L'Hospital's rule two times (doing the same trick before you differentaite the second time.